# Way to seprate each word from string and include special characters lua

Tags: string, lua

So I recently used this following lua code to separate each word from string and notice it's not showing special characters (e.g. `/,;,'`). So is there anyway for it to show?

```
string = "Test, Im testing"
for word in string:gmatch("%w+") do
print(word)
end
```

This code will not show the commas on the string but I need it to show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `%w` I think you are looking for `%S` pattern.

Alternatively you can also try `[%w%p]+`.

See a brief description of how lua pattern behave at [lua pil](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html)